# Bijection from (0,1) to R

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

I need help proving that f(x) = tan(xpi-pi/2) is a bijection where the map is from (0,1) to the Reals. I know I need to prove onto and one to one, but have little experience proving these facts with trig functions.

Comment: What things have you tried so far?

Comment: I have nothing, I have no frame of reference for an approach to this kind of proof.

Comment: Write out the definitions of "onto" and "one to one". That's it.

Comment: If I take the typical approach, I would get somthing like tan(xpi-pi/2) = tan(ypi-pi/2). I'm not sure how to solve this equation unless we can just set the stuff inside the tangents equal and solve.

Comment: Is there a possible bijection here that does not involve the function tangent?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

1. $\tan x$ is continuous and monotonic increasing in $(-{\pi \over 2},{\pi \over 2})$ and hence injective.
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to -{\pi \over 2}}=-\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to {\pi \over 2}}=\infty$ so it must be surjective.

Try to translate these facts in terms of your function.